# Show that $\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta^2(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series

I am a graduate student of Mathematics. I have started reading number theory. I encountered a problem of analytic number theory.

Show that $\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta^2(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$.

I have started by showing that $\omega(mn)=\omega(m)+\omega(n)$ for $(m,n)=1$. Which implies that $f(n)=2^{\omega(n)}$ is multiplicative.

I don't know what to do next. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Do you know what the Dirichlet convolution of two functions is?

Comment: @Mastrem Yes I know very well what is Dirichlet convolution.

Comment: Okay, well if we define $f$ as in your question, and $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}\to \mathbb{C}$ by $g(n)=1$ whenever $n$ is a perfect square and zero otherwise, and $I:\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}\to\mathbb{C}$ by $I(n)=1$ for all $n$, then $L(I,s)=\zeta(s)$ and $L(g,s)=\zeta(2s)$, and you want to show that $L(f,s)=L(I,s)^2 / L(g,s)$, which is equivalent (modulo some potential convergence issues and dividing by $0$) to $L(f*g,s)=L(I*I,s)$. Can you show that $f*g = I*I$?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882551/dirichlet-series-and-riemann-zeta-function) for $\frac{\zeta^3(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$ and imitate the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, we know

$$
2^{\omega(n)}=\prod_{p|n}(1+1)=\sum_{d|n}\mu^2(d)
$$

Moreover, it can be verified that

$$
\mu^2(d)=\sum_{d^2|n}\mu(d)
$$

This suggests that

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\ge1}{\mu^2(n)\over n^s}
&=\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over n^s}\sum_{d^2|n}\mu(d)=\sum_{d\ge1}\mu(d)\sum_{\substack{n\ge1\\d^2|n}}{1\over n^s} \\
&=\sum_{d\ge1}\mu(d)\sum_{k\ge1}{1\over(d^2k)^s}=\zeta(s)\sum_{d\ge1}{\mu(d)\over d^{2s}}
\end{aligned}

By the properties of Möbius inversion, it is evident that $\sum_{n\ge1}\mu(n)n^{-s}=1/\zeta(s)$, so using the properties of Dirichlet convolution we have

$$
\sum_{m\ge1}{2^{\omega(m)}\over m^s}=\zeta(s)\sum_{n\ge1}{\mu^2(n)\over n^s}={\zeta^2(s)\over\zeta(2s)}
$$

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is probably in the comment from Mastrem. But it's not hard to do it using Euler's product:

We have $$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s} = \prod_p \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{2^{\omega(p^k)}}{p^{ks}}= \prod_p \left(1+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{2}{p^{ks}}\right)$$

$$= \prod_p \left(1+\frac{2}{p^s-1}\right)= \prod_p \frac{p^s+1}{p^s-1}= \prod_p \frac{p^{2s}-1}{(p^s-1)^2}$$

$$= \prod_p \left(\frac{p^s}{p^s-1}\right)^2 \frac{p^{2s}-1}{p^{2s}} = \frac{\zeta(s)^2}{\zeta(2s)}$$